# Is there a triangulation of a closed surface with each vertex incident to $n\ge 7$ triangles?

Tags: geometry, graph-theory, surfaces, geometric-topology, simplicial-complex

Fix some $n\ge 7$. Is there a *finite* 2-dimensional [simplicial complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_simplicial_complex) with

- each vertex is incident to exactly $n$ triangles, and
- the complex forms a [closed surface](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Surface_(topology)#Closed_surfaces).

If the surface is not *closed*, then uniform tilings of the hyperbolic plane do the trick.

[image]

But I am specifically interested in the case of **finite closed** complexes.
So is this possible?

Since I want a surface, I made some quick computations with the Euler characteristic $\chi$ of that surface.
I found that the complex must have $-6\chi/(n-6)$ vertices.
I came not much farther than that.

Comment: I see how your definition of "2-dimensional surface" rules out connecting everything. It also seems to rule out the [Császár_polyhedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cs%C3%A1sz%C3%A1r_polyhedron) for $n=6$, though, so maybe it's too restrictive?

Comment: @MishaLavrov I do not want to exclude Császár's polyhedron (except that I am only interested in $n\ge7$), but I see how my definition excludes it. I modified the definition to what I actually want.

Comment: Related: [Degree-regular triangulations of torus and Klein bottle](https://arxiv.org/abs/math/0403433)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There does always exist such a surface. There is a reasonably short proof using a big tool, namely [Selberg's Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_group#Properties) that every linear group has a torsion free subgroup of finite index.

Assuming equilateral triangles, the symmetry group of the tiling of the hyperbolic plane $\mathbb H^2$ that you depict is a [reflection group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reflection_group). In particular, if you pick any tile, then subdivide it into 6 triangles each with angles $\pi/2$, $\pi/3$, $\pi/n$, and then take $T$ to be any one of those 6 triangles, the symmetry group is generated by reflections in the three sides of $T$. That group is a [Coxeter group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coxeter_group)
$$C(2,3,n) = \langle a,b,c \mid a^2 = b^2 = c^2 = (ab)^2 = (bc)^3 = (ca)^n = \text{Id} \rangle
$$
Furthermore, $T$ is a fundamental domain for the action of $C(2,3,n)$. These conclusions all come from the [Poincare Fundamental Polygon Theorem](https://reader.elsevier.com/reader/sd/pii/S0001870871800038?token=93CF3C4F1811CB137BD302E3429DF3C0E3BF02DA57657DFD3AFF9ED200FF1483E2873789680154689EC5EE42D1E3B820).

We can pass to an index 2 subgroup $R(2,3,n) < C(2,3,n)$ in which the sum of the exponents of $a,b,c$ in each word is even. One can show that $R(2,3,n)$ is generated by the rotations $ab$, $bc$ and $ca$ of order $2,3,n$ respectively, with defining relation $(ab)(bc)(ca) = \text{Id}$. The action of $R(2,3,n)$ on $\mathbb H^2$ therefore preserves orientation. The orientation preserving isometry group of the hyperbolic plane is a linear group, namely $SO(2,1)$. Selberg's Lemma therefore applies, yielding a torsion free finite index subgroup $\Gamma < R(2,3,n) < C(2,3,n)$. The quotient $\mathbb H^2 / \Gamma$ is the surface that you desire.

Comment: Thank you for this awesome answer. Can we stretch this more and get *arbitrarily large* such complexes for a fixed $n$?

Comment: Yes. The "size" of the complex, let's say the number of vertices, is proportional to the index of the subgroup (plus or minus an amount bounded independently of the index). And $\Gamma$ contains finite index subgroups of arbitrarily large index.

Answer (score 4):

For $n=7$ there are models of the **Klein quartic** such as those shown below, taken from https://www.semanticscholar.org/paper/Polyhedral-models-of-Felix-Klein-%CC%81-s-Quartic/54dd0ddc8a3ed8996ed85bf0fc7daf898dac8085.  This page cites References [1] and [2] as the original sources.

[image]

Figure 1 represents a complex, heavily folded but non-self-intersecting, tetrahedral symmetric polyhedron with 24 vertices, 84 edges and 56 faces, corresponding to an Euler characteristic of -4 and thus a genus of 3.  Figure 2, with the same count of faces, edges and vertices and octahedral symmetry, is easier to visualize but contains self-intersections.  In both cases all faces are triangular and seven of them meet at each vertex, corresponding to the ratio 56/24=7/3 between faces and vertices.

Schulte and Willis [3] list regular polyhedral maps of genus from 2 to 6, or more precisely genus 3,5, or 6 as none exist with genus 2 or 4.  The triangular solutions for $n=7$ are the Klein quartic models described above.  Additional solutions, both non-self-intersecting and self-intersecting with higher symmetry, are identified with $n=8$ and $n=10$, the former including two different polyhedra with different face/edge/vertex sizes and different genus.  In general, solutions for a given $n\ge 7$ require higher genus to accommodate more faces, so only a finite number of solutions can be realized for any $n$ with a bounded genus.

Reference [3] also includes low-genus hyperbolic polyhedra made with squares, pentagons or hexagons.

References

1.
E. Schulte, J.M. Wills, "A polyhedral realization of Felix Klein's map on a Riemann
surface of genus 3", J. London Math. Soc. 32 (1985) 539-547.

2.
E. Schulte, J.M. Wills, "Kepler-Poinsot-type realization of regular maps of Klein, Fricke,
Gordon and Sherk", Canad. Math. Bull. 30 (1987) 155-164.

3.
Egon Schulte and Jorg M. Wills, "Convex-Faced Combinatorially Regular Polyhedra of Small Genus", Symmetry 2012, 4, 1-14; [doi:10.3390/sym4010001](https://www.mdpi.com/2073-8994/4/1/1/notes).